# Programmatically call spring cloud config actuator/env post endpoint in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud config in my spring boot application, I am trying to update the property value through actuator/env post endpoint.

Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class ActuatorRefreshService {

  private final String inventoryModeKey = "inventory.initial.mode";
  private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

  @Autowired
  public ActuatorRefreshService() {
  }

  public void refreshStatus(String latestMode) {
    Map<String, String> bodyMap = new HashMap();
    bodyMap.put("name",inventoryModeKey);
    bodyMap.put("value",latestMode);
    webClient.post().uri("/actuator/env")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .body(Mono.just(bodyMap), Map.class).retrieve().onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        return Mono.error(new Exception("error"));
    }).bodyToMono(String.class);
    System.out.println("call actuator endpoint to update the value");

  }
}
```

When I am calling my rest endpoint that calls this `refreshStatus` method. The api returns me 200 status. After that I hit `localhost:8080/actuator/refresh`. When I check the updated value , it shows this `__refreshAll__`.

I have no idea why is this happening?? Any help would be appreciated.

**Note :*** When I hit the endpoint  localhost:8080/actuator/env from postman and refresh then it updates the property.*

I tried with `localhost:8080/actuator/busenv` bus endpoint as well but still no luck.
Anyone tried this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to call this api `localhost:8080/actuator/busenv` programmatically in spring boot using `RestTemplate in spring`. It is refreshing the configuration as well in application context. I am not sure why it didn't work with `WebClient` though.

***posting the answer if anyone else is looking for the same requirement.***

Please find the below code

```
@Service
public class ActuatorRefreshService {

   private final String inventoryModeKey = "inventory.initial.mode";

   @Autowired
   public ActuatorRefreshService() {
   }

   public void refreshInventoryMode(String latestMode) {
      Map<String, String> bodyMap = new HashMap();
      bodyMap.put("name",inventoryModeKey);
      bodyMap.put("value",latestMode);
      final String url = "http://localhost:8080/actuator/busenv";

      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    


      headers
      .setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

      HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);
      restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
      System.out.println("call actuator endpoint to update the value ");

}
```

}